# Conda update fails due to Python version in "base" environment

Tags: python, conda

I installed Anaconda on Windows 10 as administrator.  I ran the Conda prompt with my non-administrator account and created a `py39` environment for Python 3.9:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
                         C:\Users\User.Name\.conda\envs\py39
```

I started to install PySpark according to [this](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/install-pyspark-in-anaconda-jupyter-notebook) page, which requires `conda install openjdk` beforehand.  I mistakenly installed that in the base environment as administrator.  In the process, I was notified that I needed to update Conda:

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 23.1.0
  latest version: 23.5.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda

Or to minimize the number of packages updated
during conda update use

     conda install conda=23.5.0
```

While I could be mistaken, I'm pretty sure that I ran the 1st of the 2 Conda update commands before I realized that I needed `openjdk` in environment `py39`.  So I uninstalled `openjdk` and started a Conda prompt under the non-administrator account in order to install `openjdk` under environment `py39`.  This worked without incident, but I was given the *same* warning to update Conda.

When I tried the 1st of the above two commands again, I got the message "All requested packages already installed."  I assumed that it was because I cannot affect the base environment from the non-administrator account.  I tried with the administrator account but got the same result.

Still under the administrator account, I then tried the 2nd of the two commands, `conda install conda=23.5.0`.  I got the following puzzling result:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install conda=23.5.0
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve.
Retrying with flexible solve.

Solving environment: failed with repodata from
current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve.
Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your
environment:

Specifications:

  - conda=23.5.0 -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.11,<3.12.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the
version you've asked for.

When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on
the left is somehow not available for the python version you are
constrained to. Note that conda will not change your python
version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.
```

I sort of understand. The base environment has python 3.7, but that's the point of having created the `py39` environment, i.e., to leave the "virgin" base environment undisturbed.

Conda is supposed to be for environment/package management, including Python version, so I am puzzled by why upgrading Conda has a dependence on the Python version in a particular environment.

Is this a proper understanding of the situation?  If not, how else can I probe the Conda installation to find out what is wrong?

**Afternote 2023-07-06** After almost a week, the update finished but the Python version was still 3.7 in the base environment.  I'm not sure what to look for in the [voluminous output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76630233/interpreting-conda-update-messages) to determine what could be wrong.  I uninstalled Anadconda, re-installed it with Python 3.10, re-created environment *py39* with Python 3.9, and re-installed Open JDK and PySpark.

Comment: Python 3.7 is unsupported as of this week (https://devguide.python.org/versions/). Conda actually dropped Python 3.7 support slightly earlier (in the 23.3.0 release in March: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/release-notes.html#id7). So your choice is either: (a) upgrade Python in the base env, or (b) restrict yourself to Conda <= 23.1.0.

Comment: I'm new to Python and [Ana]conda. I've read in many places that one should create new environments to upgrade Python, and especially *installing* major upgrades. Such advice cites (for example) [this](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#updating-or-upgrading-python) document passage. Is it correct to say that this is good practice *except* when the Python version in the base environment is no longer supported?

Comment: *"Is it correct to say that this is good practice except when the Python version in the base environment is no longer supported?*" Yes, IMO.

Comment: I'm finding that upgrading Python is a hazardous operation with resolution of dependencies that can take a week or more, without guarantee of success.

Comment: Furthermore, it is a fragile operation on Windows because the CMD window can halt the process if you click anywhere on the terminal window. That inadvertently initiates a copy/paste which doesn't terminate until you press <Enter>, but it *does* halt the resolution of dependencies without *any* indication other than the fact that the CPU usage drops to near zero in the Task Manager.  Essentially, it looks as if it hanged. I lost the last 15 hours to this..  This would *never* happen with an *xterm*.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.7 has reached its end of support. This means that no more security updates or bug fixes will be released for this version of Python. If you are still using Python 3.7, you have two choices:

1. Upgrade to a supported version of Python. This will ensure that you have the latest features, bug fixes, and security updates.
2. Continue using Python 3.7, but use a Conda version that still supports it. Conda versions up to 23.1.0 still support Python 3.7.
   It is important to stay updated with the latest software versions to benefit from improved functionality and security enhancements.

If you are unsure which version of Python to use, you can consult the Python documentation: https://devguide.python.org/versions/.

Comment: Regarding option #1, is it appropriate to formalize in your answer that, though upgrading Python to another branch [is not recommended](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#updating-or-upgrading-python) (compared to creating a new environment), this situation is an exception? Apart from that, I'm not sure why anyone would *want* to change the base environment other than to upgrade [Ana]conda. From my Googling, you typically create other environments if you want something specific and kept up to date. Then again, I'm new to [Ana]conda and Python.

Comment: The update has been going on for 16 hours. Googling shows that some package updates can go for a week, and then they don't always succeed. This is a *serious* problem.  I can't even initiate a new install of Anaconda while the update is attempted.  So it's all-or-nothing in that you have to decide whether to upgrade, which can take 1+ week without success, or forgo even the attempt, uninstall Anaconda, re-install from scratch, and recreate Conda environments.

Comment: @user2153235 I don't think any update should ever go on for a week let alone more than a few hours at most. if there's a problem you always backup your environments to a file so you can clean install.

Comment: There have been reports other than mine of such long updates, but like mine, I vaguely recall that failed updates at the end of the long duration were not uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I don't recommend changing Python versions in place for Conda environments, but as pointed out in comments and [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76592852/570918), v3.7 is EOL so it is clearly justified.

There are better options in my opinion for **base** environments<sup>**1**</sup>, but let's assume you want to keep Anaconda. You need to update at minimum:

- `conda`
- `anaconda`
- `python`

A key thing to note here is that, unless you tell Conda it is allowed to update Python, it considers that as off limits. Instead of using exact versions, specify a minimum for `anaconda` and `conda` to ensure that they continue to update into the future:

```bash
conda install -n base 'anaconda>=2023.07' 'conda>=23.05' python=3.10
```

I show Python 3.10 here as I regard it as the latest stable version in "Condaverse" (e.g., 3.11 still hasn't finished rolling out on Conda Forge).

If you have serious issues with solve times, then use Micromamba to operate on your environment externally. Something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75699320/570918), but with:

```
micromamba install -n base 'anaconda>=2023.07' 'conda>=23.05' python=3.10
```

I think that latest versions of Conda are defaulting to the `libmamba` solver, so solving should be much improved after upgrading (you don't need to keep Micromamba around if you don't want to).

---

<sub>**[1]:** [Mambaforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge) is my standing recommend. Though, I expect in the next year, there will finally be a Micromamba distribution that includes updating and ends this ridiculous state of depending on a **base** environment at all.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, merv!  I've been tending to other issues but I did do some background reading on mamba. However, the current resolution of conflicts seems to be near completion, so I will cross my fingers and hope that it succeeds. If it doesn't, I may try mamba, but I'll more likely un-install and re-install Anaconda, then recreate my Python 3.9 environment.  As a beginner, I'm not keen on the idea of exploring new variations on Conda because I don't have to experience to recognize when things aren't as they should be or what could be the cause.