# Interpreting conda update messages

Tags: conda

Python 3.7 reached end-oflife, so I had to upgrade to version 3.9 in the base environment, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592503/conda-update-fails-due-to-python-version-in-base-environment).  It has taken 6 days, and it seemed poised to finish last night, when the progress was at 99%.  This seemed inline with the progression over the past 6 days, which was approximately linear at 15% per day.

I am surprised, however, that the progress didn't go from 99% to 100% over the past 12 hours.  I am not sure how to interpret the progress update messages.  The following is what I see at the Conda prompt.

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install python=3.9
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining conflict for zict _anaconda_depends anaconda distributed: : 404it [134:16:25, 785.73s/it\                                           \
```

Unfortunately, on Windows, the progress messages overwrite each other on the same physical line.  The last line is the only thing that changed in the past 6 days: Sometimes, I see a percentage (presumably of completion), other times, I see mysterious metrics.  Currently, the line ends with a backslash followed by a wide horizontal gap and a terminating backslash.  The 2nd last backslash sometimes overwrites the preceding "t" in "it", and it constantly spins like a dial.

*Is there anyway way to have the updates *not* overwrite each other?* Currently, there is no way to see the last percentage completion.

**Is there any documentation on interpreting the metrics?**

For example, does "it" stand for "item"?  Is the 134:16:25 the elapsed time?  It doesn't change, but it works out to about 5.5 days, which seems about right. (Correction: It changed, but likely only when the line item changed and not "live" like the spinning dial).

I was hoping that more certainty in the interpretation of the metrics might allow for speculation on why 12+ hours isn't sufficient for progress to go from 99% to 100%.  It doesn't seem to be in-line with the 15%/day seen so far.

The uncertainty in the remaining dependency analysis makes it very difficult to plan.  I can't schedule when commute to other locations because if the update is not finished, it means putting the laptop to sleep.  I don't want to do that because I don't know if it will break week-long update.  Finishing the update is my first priority, since it has pretty well prevented any work.

**Afternote 2023-07-06 15:49** The update completed and a high volume of output was sent to the CMD console -- more than could be buffered by the console. Issuing `python --version` shows that it is still 3.7.3.  Is the entirety of the high volume output captured in a file by default?  What does one look for to determine whether there is any point in further attempts?  Thank you for any advice about this for future reference.  My immediate way ahead is to uninstall and re-install Anaconda, since the attempted upgrade has taken nearly a week.

Comment: In the last line of the output, the right most backslash (which doesn't spin) sometimes shows as a dash.  It may be that some long update lines push the spinning dial to the right, and the terminating backslash or dash is a remnant of that.