# Cannot update conda on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, conda

I use conda in MacOS terminal to install an open-source software, which include a few key steps.

1. First, create an environment for the package by running `conda env create --name weis-env -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WISDEM/WEIS/main/environment.yml python=3.9`
   This command is to create a virtual environment called weis-env from the file environment.yml, with python 3.9 installed. But when I check the version of python after running, it is python=3.10.13 (see below). I don't know why this happens.

```
(weis-env) MacBook-Air-2:~ wuying$ conda --version 
conda 4.9.2
(weis-env) MacBook-Air-2:~ wuying$ python --version 
Python 3.10.13
```

2. Second, install dependencies outside of environment file.

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge 
conda install -y compilers（mac only）
```

When run above command, I receive the following error：

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - python=3.1
```

It seems that conda tends to request python 3.1 when python 3.10 is installed. And also conda 4.9 has to be upgraded if want to use python 3.10 and newer. So I run `conda update conda` in base environment, but receive the following error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): - WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(540): Using .* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.7.1.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1.7.1
done
Solving environment: | 
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:
...
```

Can anyone tell me how can I solve this problem?

3. Basic information of my conda

```
MacBook-Air-2:~ wuying$ conda info

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /Users/wuying/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/wuying/.condarc
          conda version : 4.9.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.9
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=10.14.6=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /usr/local/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /usr/local/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /Users/wuying/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /usr/local/anaconda3/envs
                          /Users/wuying/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.9.2 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Darwin/18.7.0 OSX/10.14.6
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: There are directions in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76596415/570918 You can use `python=3.11 'conda>=23.09'`. Possibly we can close this as a duplicate. I would recommend using the `micromamba` approach. Also when solving for the **base**, specify `-c defaults -c conda-forge` to ensure that Conda Forge is not the highest priority (it is incompatible with Anaconda **base**).

Comment: Did you ever tell conda where to find your desired python?

Comment: @merv Thanks, merv! Do you mean run `conda install -n base 'anaconda>=2023.07' 'conda>=23.09' python=3.11` in the terminal? In fact, I still receive the error "Solving environment: | The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully".

Comment: Does it finish updating?

Comment: @merv No, the update and installation of packages cannot start. I uninstall and reinstall anaconda3 in macbook and the problem is solved. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use Conda Forge, you really should install Miniforge, not Anaconda. Anaconda doesn't play well with the Conda Forge channel.