# conda environment.yaml package conflict

Tags: conda, mamba

When I'm trying to build a git [project](https://github.com/zju3dv/OnePose_Plus_Plus), the environment,yml won't work properly. It seems like some package conflict, but other user doesn't seem to run into this issue, and I couldn't figure out a solution. My conda version is conda 4.8.2,and down below is the environment.yaml, requirment.txt and error

environment.yml:

```
name: oneposeplus
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - pytorch=1.8.0
  - torchvision=0.9.1
  - cudatoolkit=10.1
  - ipython
  - tqdm
  - matplotlib
  - pylint
  - conda-forge::jupyterlab
  - conda-forge::h5py=3.1.0
  - conda-forge::loguru=0.5.3
  - conda-forge::scipy
  - conda-forge::numba
  - conda-forge::ipdb
  - conda-forge::albumentations=0.5.1
  - pip
  - pip:
    - -r requirements.txt
```

requirment.txt:

```
pytorch-lightning==1.5.10
ray==1.13.0
aiohttp==3.7
aioredis==1.3.1
pydegensac==0.1.2
opencv_python==4.4.0.46
yacs>=0.1.8
pytorch_memlab
joblib
pytorch3d
open3d
einops==0.3.0
kornia==0.4.1
autopep8
pickle5==0.0.11
timm>=0.3.2
hydra-core
omegaconf
pycocotools
wandb
rich
transforms3d
natsort
plyfile
pycolmap==0.3.0
```

error:

```
rvl224@eervl224:~/OnePose_Plus_Plus-main$ conda env create -f environment.yaml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining conflict for pylint numba python matplotlib jupyterlab ipython tqdm scExamining conflict for pylint numba python matplotlib torchvision jupyterlab ipyExamining conflict for pylint numba python matplotlib torchvision jupyterlab ipyExamining conflict for pylint jupyterlab ipython: : 20it [06:56, 20.25s/it]     Examining conflict for albumentations numba matplotlib torchvision h5py scipy pyExamining conflict for albumentations numba matplotlib torchvision h5py scipy pyExamining conflict for albumentations torchvision: : 24it [08:51,  8.89s/it]    Examining conflict for albumentations pytorch torchvision: : 25it [09:21, 37.46sExamining conflict for albumentations pytorch torchvision: : 26it [09:21, 35.40sExamining conflict for albumentations h5py: : 26it [09:35, 35.40s/it]           Examining conflict for albumentations matplotlib torchvision: : 27it [09:41, 28.Examining conflict for albumentations matplotlib torchvision: : 28it [09:41, 21.Examining conflict for albumentations matplotlib: : 28it [10:08, 21.91s/it]     Examining conflict for albumentations numba matplotlib torchvision scipy: : 29itExamining conflict for albumentations numba matplotlib torchvision scipy: : 30itExamining conflict for albumentations numba python matplotlib torchvision h5py cExamining conflict for albumentations numba python matplotlib torchvision h5py cExamining conflict for albumentations pytorch: : 31it [11:39, 25.74s/it]        failed                                                                  

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1079, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main.py", line 80, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/cli/main_create.py", line 111, in execute
        result[installer_type] = installer.install(prefix, pkg_specs, args, env)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda_env/installers/conda.py", line 32, in install
        prune=getattr(args, 'prune', False), update_modifier=UpdateModifier.FREEZE_INSTALLED)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 117, in solve_for_transaction
        should_retry_solve)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 158, in solve_for_diff
        force_remove, should_retry_solve)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 281, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._run_sat(ssc)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 808, in _run_sat
        should_retry_solve=ssc.should_retry_solve
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 1318, in solve
        self.find_conflicts(specs, specs_to_add, history_specs)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 347, in find_conflicts
        bad_deps = self.build_conflict_map(specs, specs_to_add, history_specs)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 507, in build_conflict_map
        root, search_node, dep_graph, num_occurances)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/resolve.py", line 369, in breadth_first_search_for_dep_graph
        last_spec = MatchSpec.union((path[-1], target_paths[-1][-1]))[0]
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/match_spec.py", line 481, in union
        return cls.merge(match_specs, union=True)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/match_spec.py", line 475, in merge
        reduce(lambda x, y: x._merge(y, union), group) if len(group) > 1 else group[0]
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/match_spec.py", line 475, in <lambda>
        reduce(lambda x, y: x._merge(y, union), group) if len(group) > 1 else group[0]
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/match_spec.py", line 502, in _merge
        final = this_component.union(that_component)
      File "/home/rvl224/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/models/match_spec.py", line 764, in union
        return '|'.join(options)
    TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Channel found

`$ /home/rvl224/anaconda3/bin/conda-env create -f environment.yaml`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic
  CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false
                CONDA_EXE=/home/rvl224/anaconda3/bin/conda
         CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/home/rvl224/anaconda3/bin/python
               CONDA_ROOT=/home/rvl224/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=0
            DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
          LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/lib:/opt/ros/noetic/lib/x86_64-linux-
                          gnu:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:
           MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
                     PATH=/home/rvl224/anaconda3/bin:/home/rvl224/anaconda3/condabin:/opt/ros/no
                          etic/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/rvl224/.local/bin:/home/rvl224/.loc
                          al/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/u
                          sr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
          PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/noetic/lib/x86_64-linux-
                          gnu/pkgconfig
               PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
         ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/share
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
               WINDOWPATH=2

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /home/rvl224/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/rvl224/.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.2
    conda-build version : 3.18.11
         python version : 3.7.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=12.0
                          __glibc=2.31
       base environment : /home/rvl224/anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/rvl224/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/rvl224/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/rvl224/anaconda3/envs
                          /home/rvl224/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.2 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.6 Linux/5.15.0-76-generic ubuntu/20.04.4 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

[y/N]: 
Timeout reached. No report sent.
```

down below are attempt updates to fix the error:
installing micromamba:

```
## install micromamba
curl micro.mamba.pm/install.sh | bash
export MAMBA_ROOT_PREFIX=/home/rvl224/anaconda3
micromamba update -n base conda

micromamba create -n oneposeplus -f environment.yaml
```

stuck at:

```
pkgs/main/linux-64                                            No change
pkgs/r/linux-64                                               No change
pkgs/r/noarch                                                 No change
pkgs/main/noarch                                              No change
pytorch/linux-64                                              No change
pytorch/noarch                                                No change
conda-forge/noarch                                  11.7MB @   2.3MB/s  5.2s
conda-forge/linux-64                                29.2MB @   4.4MB/s  6.9s
```

install mamba

```
#install mamba
micromamba install -c conda-forge mamba --root-prefix=/home/rvl224/anaconda3 -n base

mamba create -n oneposeplus -f environment.yaml
```

error:

```
Looking for: ['environment.yaml']

warning  libmamba Could not parse mod/etag header
warning  libmamba Could not parse mod/etag header
warning  libmamba Could not parse mod/etag header
warning  libmamba Could not parse mod/etag header
warning  libmamba Could not parse mod/etag header
warning  libmamba Could not parse mod/etag header
pkgs/main/noarch                                   851.4kB @   1.3MB/s  0.7s
pkgs/r/linux-64                                      1.4MB @   1.6MB/s  0.9s
pkgs/r/noarch                                        1.3MB @   1.0MB/s  0.6s
pkgs/main/linux-64                                 @   2.5MB/s  2.4s
conda-forge/noarch                                 @   3.0MB/s  4.6s
conda-forge/linux-64                               @   4.8MB/s  7.4s
Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides requested environment.yaml
```

tried installing packages one by one in a test environmemt,down below are some error while installing:

```
mamba install -n test_environment cudatoolkit=10.1 --yes

Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides pytorch 1.10.2 cpu_py37h76afcab_0 needed by pytorch-cpu-1.10.2-cpu_py37h718b53a_0


mamba install -n test_environment "conda-forge::h5py=3.1.0" --yes

Encountered problems while solving:
  - package pulseaudio-daemon-16.1-ha8d29e2_3 requires openssl >=3.1.0,<4.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed

mamba install -n test_environment -c conda-forge -c pytorch -c defaults --file requirements.txt --yes


Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides requested ray 1.13.0
  - nothing provides requested pydegensac 0.1.2
  - nothing provides requested opencv_python 4.4.0.46
  - nothing provides requested pytorch_memlab
  - nothing provides requested pytorch3d
  - nothing provides requested open3d
  - nothing provides requested kornia 0.4.1
  - package pycolmap-0.3.0-cpu_py39h5202583_1 requires python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0, but none of the providers can be installed
```

change into:

```
cudatoolkit=10.2
h5py (without version)
```

still figuring what to do with requirement.txt

Comment: Update Conda and try again. Note you may need to update Python in the **base** environment as well, since Python v3.7 is EOL. E.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/76596415/570918 (note I strongly recommend the `micromamba` approach for this - `conda` can literally take days to solve Anaconda **base** + `conda-forge` prioritized channel)

Comment: @merv I've tried "conda install -n base 'anaconda>=2023.07' 'conda>=23.05' python=3.10" ,which stuck at "solving environment" forever. Tried to install micromamba  "conda install -c conda-forge micromamba", stuck at  "Examining conflict for _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf cffi ipywidgets pytest-astropy-header backcall jsons" for hours now. I've reinstall conda before the posted problem in an attempt to solve it myself, weird that conflicts kept popping out since it should be a clean conda in my perspective.

Comment: Micromamba is not a Conda package - it is a standalone binary you use to operation on Conda environments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75690726/cant-update-conda-after-3-years-away/75699320#75699320

Comment: welp conflict again:

error    libmamba Could not solve for environment specs

    The following package could not be installed
    └─ anaconda >=2023.07  is not installable because it requires
       └─ _openmp_mutex 5.1 1_gnu, which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

btw this was what I found when trying to install micromamba before https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/micromamba

Comment: Since you have Micromamba installed, can you simply create the environment from that? E.g., `micromamba create -n oneposeplus -f environment.yml`

Comment: It freezes at "conda-forge/noarch                                  11.7MB @   3.5MB/s  3.4s
conda-forge/linux-64                               @   3.2MB/s  9.3s
" I gave it two hours and it remains the same, restarted the process and stuck at same spot.

Comment: Tried "micromamba install -c conda-forge mamba --root-prefix=/home/rvl224/anaconda3 -n base

" then "mamba create -n oneposeplus -f environment.yaml

" got "Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides requested environment.yaml"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to manually install every package,idk why environment.yml doesn't work

```
mamba create -n oneposeplus python=3.7 --yes
conda activate oneposeplus

pip install torch==1.8.0 --no-input
pip install torchvision==0.9.1 --no-input
pip install matplotlib --no-input
pip install ipython --no-input
pip install tqdm --no-input
pip install pylint --no-input
pip install jupyterlab --no-input
pip install "h5py==3.1.0" --no-input
pip install loguru==0.5.3 --no-input
pip install scipy --no-input
pip install numba --no-input
pip install ipdb --no-input
pip install "albumentations==0.5.1" --no-input

pip install pytorch-lightning==1.5.10 --no-input
pip install ray==1.13.0 --no-input
pip install aiohttp==3.7 --no-input
pip install aioredis==1.3.1 --no-input
pip install pydegensac==0.1.2 --no-input
pip install opencv-python==4.4.0.46 --no-input
pip install "yacs>=0.1.8" --no-input
pip install pytorch_memlab --no-input
pip install joblib --no-input
pip install pytorch3d --no-input
pip install open3d --no-input
pip install "einops==0.3.0" --no-input
pip install "kornia==0.4.1" --no-input
pip install autopep8 --no-input
pip install "pickle5==0.0.11" --no-input
pip install "timm>=0.3.2" --no-input
pip install hydra-core --no-input
pip install omegaconf --no-input
pip install pycocotools --no-input
pip install wandb --no-input
pip install rich --no-input
pip install transforms3d --no-input
pip install natsort --no-input
pip install plyfile --no-input
pip install "pycolmap==0.3.0" --no-input
```

Thanks for @merv for helping.